Having difficulty playing a part of Turkish March on guitar
I'm learning the Turkish March from a YouTube tutorial. I'm having problem playing the following part that was played at this timestamp.

I can place my index finger similar to the above image and play the third frets of the first and fifth strings simultaneously, but I cannot play the next double note properly, because the fourth string is muted. This was also the case for the second next double note. From the video, it seems that the player's index finger doesn't move at all to unmute the strings. Could you please explain how to play this part of the music?
Edit:
To clarify it, my problem is that when I place my index finger similar to the image to press third fret of the first and fifth string, the fourth string will be muted if I don't move my index finger away from the strings.

It doesn't matter that the index finger does not move, because the next note (on the fourth string) is higher up on the neck, fretted by the middle finger.  You can't mute a fretted note behind the stopped fret.
Or maybe I misunderstood the problem?

Thanks, my problem is that when I place my index finger similar to the image to press third fret of the first and fifth string, the fourth string will be muted if I don't move my index finger away from the strings.

While you should be able to barre the fret and have no strings muted, you don't need to here- every time you play the 4th string, you're fretting it at the 5th fret, so it doesn't matter what's going on at the 3rd fret.

I really don't understand the problem, but you could try barring all 6 strings for that bar. After all, that's what the III signifies. But even when you only barre fret3 from strings 5 to 1, there shouldn't be a problem. Try what I suggest and it will at least sound smoother, and probably be easier to play. The playing in the video leaves something to be desired...
And you ought to be able to play the barre and the note 2 frets higher with ease - it's part of a bog standard barre chord.

Thanks for the suggestion, I actually didn't know anything about barring and the III notation.

The III doesn't actually signify the barre.  It identifies the position on the fretboard you are playing in, defined by the fret you use the index finger for.  The barre indicator is the horizontal line extending to the right of the III, which ends at the end where the short vertical line is.
